# Is there a way to stop this code from opening a new browser window each time?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Process.Start(url);
```

Everytime this code executes, I get a new tab in my browser, showing the content of url.
Is there a way to prevent the 'new tab' behaviour and open in the same tab/window each time?

(I would prefer not to use a WebBrowser Control for security reasons.)

I am building a desktop application: not ASP.NET

Comment: +1: I always hated the applications that opens a browser in a new window.

Comment: I would recommend against over-writing a user's tab, they might have something important in that tab that you just killed, maybe an unsent email or they might be in the middle of filling up a form. I understand if you want to avoid a new window but opening a new tab is perfectly reasonable. and based on my tests that's what most browsers do.

Comment: Hmm. Except this isnt a web app, and that wasn't what I was suggesting :) I want to open in the same named window each time, so that on the first occasion, it opens a new window/tab and subsequently uses that tab.

Comment: I really advise against such design (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to do that (at least in any direct fashion) from your application. When you ask the system to start the process via Process.Start, it is up to the target application (the browser in this case) to decide how it handles the request.  So to do that, it would probably be necessary to adjust some setting in the browser (e.g., Chrome) itself.

Comment: That is what I suspected. I have been trying tricks like `url = @"javascript:void(window.open('" + url + "','win'));";` - without any luck in firefox

Comment: @Tom:  I am currently working on a couple of applications that, for various reasons, use Process.Start (or something equivalent) and they all start up new tabs in my browser.  And I find it somewhat annoying but haven't found a solution.  So I guess I am hoping my answer is wrong; it would be nice to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, no.

Process.Start() creates a new process server side and executes whatever command that you give it as an argument.  Most browers would see it as a breach of security to compromise a currenly running process.

I'm assuming here that you're using ASP.NET and a web browser and so I'd recomment that you should look for a client-side solution to open a new tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function runsomestuff() {
    document.getElementById('mylink').click();
  }
</script>

<body onload="runsomestuff">
 ... 
 <a href="some url" target="_blank" id="mylink" style="display: none;">content of the anchor</a>
</body>
```

Note that this code hasn't been tested.  By using an onclick for a link you are forcing the client brower to take acknowledgement of the target for the link.  And the browser can then sort out how it will display that link (most will do a new tab, but others (IE6) will always open a new window.

Please post some more code specifically so that we can see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. However, I am building a desktop application. I have added this to the question.

Comment: Actually from a winforms POV you could try using Process Start Info and passing arguments into Process.Start from there.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)

Comment: Yes I tried that. If the browser was closed in the first place then one can save the reference to the process returned by process.start and then kill it before starting a new one. However, this just doesn't work well, for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

May be kill the process and start again everytime.

you should be able to preserve the PID for future calls.

Comment: This kind of worked but not nicely, since the browser has to be closed originally. And each time. It ends up being slow and unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute an URL that way you are asking the Shell to do it for you. Meaning the shell determines what browser, and hands it over according to the browsers registration. Usually this means opening a new window, but that is up to the application receiving the URL.

If you want to take control of this default behaviour you need to read what the URL handler is from registry, then for each browser type implement handling routines that can locate the window and tell it to navigate.

If this is to annoying then I would suggest instead making your own mini-browser using WebBrowser control. I'm not sure what security concerns you have here (as it is just using IE) - feel free to share them.

**Edit:**
Come to think of it - default behaviour (for IE atleast) window ids is that any named target will be reused in the same window. So simply open a HTML-page that opens your destination URL in a named window, then close the window of the temporary HTML-frame. Sort of like a redirect service which targets a certain window name.

Not really sure, but a local HTML-file might have permission to open popup in JS via using something like window.open(url,'name'...

Comment: This is the most useful answer. And actually I did end up using a WebBrowser control. I considered the open an html page approach, however, its closing it automatically that presents a problem, since web pages are only allowed to close themselves on user interaction.

Comment: My security concerns were nothing more than a fear of IE based on all the vulnerabilities it has had over the years. Nothing specific. It will be web pages 'in the wild' that are loaded, so just wanted to be careful. But since there doesnt seem to be a real answer to my question, I didnt have much choice. Perhaps I could disable scripting in my main IE and this would carry over to the WB control.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I would have to say no, and strongly advise against it. If you really wanted to accomplish this, you would want to consider each web browser on the market, because you would have to pass a command line parameter to the application, and I am sure each web browser is not the same in that regard.

Process.Start("http://www.someurl.com") will start the users default web browser, so it may not be Internet Explorer. Furthermore, quite alot of people *despise* when a program opens a web page without asking.

Even moreso, if you accomplished this task how you wanted and the user did later use that web browser for something important, well, thats the tab/window you stored to use, and you would still be navigating away from that important data. You have control over what your program does, but most certainly not the user and that is something you must account for.