# How to Open a Web Page in the same tab in C#

Tags: c#, web

I am writing a Windows Form Application and I need a way to open a web page on the same tab (without opening a new tab).

if i use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

It will open in a new tab .

Comment: embed a browser object into your app and redirect the object to the web page you desire: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question. [Is there a way to stop this code from opening a new browser window each time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542733/is-there-a-way-to-stop-this-code-from-opening-a-new-browser-window-each-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: You cannot target Tabs by calling the process again - maybe with a browser plugin but consider - you may have different Browsers... I dont think this is possible in a effective way

Comment: Thanks For your comments. I understand now that I should try another way .